# Enviar cabeçalhos na requisição http angular

Tags: angular, http, angular-5

Preciso enviar três valores no meu header em requisição http, porém quando confiro no navegador eu percebo que meus headers não foram enviados.

Tentei algo como:

```
  trocaToken(token):Observable<any>{
    const _headers = new HttpHeaders();
    const headers = _headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('token', token);
    headers.append('Authorization',  'bearer ' + token);
    return this._http.post<Usuario>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'admin/detalhes',
    {headers: headers})
  }
```

Comment: Quando a requisição é Post o Primeiro dado após a vírgula é o Body, 
Tenta fazer:
`trocaToken(token):Observable<any>{
    const _headers = new HttpHeaders();
    const headers = _headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('token', token);
    headers.append('Authorization',  'bearer ' + token);
    return this._http.post<Usuario>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'admin/detalhes', { } , 
    {headers: headers})
  }`

Comment: você está usando http.post ou um httpClient?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo pelo método usado (post com tipagem em <>), ela está usando HttpClient.

Comment: @mutlei Bem observado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
  trocaToken(token):Observable<any>{
     const httpOptions = {
     headers: new HttpHeaders({
        Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'token': token
     })
  };

  return this.http.post<Usuario>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'admin/detalhes', undefined, httpOptions)
}
```